# How to change tabs width in material UI

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I am using  material UI tabs v0.20.0 for display content in tabular format. Tabs are taking full width. I have attached screenshot of expected and current output .

Expected output [image]

Current Output
[image]

Please let me know a solution for the same.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and learn how to ask questions on StackOverflow

Answer (score 20):

If you want tabs of fixed width, you need to override the `root` css class passed to the `Tab` component, where you have to override both the `minWidth` and `width` attributes.

Example:

```
const Component = ({ classes }) => (
    <Tabs value={0}>
        <Tab classes={{ root: classes.tab }} label="One" />
        <Tab classes={{ root: classes.tab }} label="Two" />
    </Tabs>
);


// this is injected as classes prop into the wrapping component
const styles = {
    tab: {
        minWidth: 200, // a number of your choice
        width: 200, // a number of your choice
    }
};
export default withStyles(styles)(Component);
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter what you call it ;)

Answer (score 10):

The `Tabs` component does accept a `variant` prop. One of the following string values are accepted:

- **fullWidth** -> which is OPs current result
- **standard** -> which is the default
- **scrollable** -> adding scrolling functionality via buttons if not all tab items are visible

By now, the OPs expected result should be the default prop (standard).

Official Docs:

- Tabs Guide: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/
- Tabs API: https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/

Answer (score 7):

setting the minWidth to 50% does the job

```
<Tabs value={value} style={{backgroundColor:"#121858",color:"#FFF"}} onChange= 
         {handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example" >
        <Tab label="Tab One" {...a11yProps(0)} style={{minWidth:"50%"}}/>
         <Tab label="Tab Two" {...a11yProps(1)}  style={{minWidth:"50%"}}/>
 </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 4):

responsive solution :-

```
 <Tabs variant="fullWidth">  </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to hardcode a tab width:

```
const width = 200;

const widthModifier = {
  width: `${width}px`,
};
```

And then apply it to change the tab width:

```
<Tab label="Item One" style={widthModifier}>
```

You're also going to have to keep track of the current active tab using `onActive` and calculate the displacement of the ink bar yourself. Here's a full working example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';

const styles = {
  headline: {
    fontSize: 24,
    paddingTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 12,
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
};

const width = 200;

const widthModifier = {
  width: `${width}px`,
};

class TabWidth extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { selectedIndex: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedIndex } = this.state;

    // Notice that I have to calculate the left position of the ink bar here for things to look right
    return (
      <Tabs inkBarStyle={ {left: `${width * selectedIndex}px`, ...widthModifier}}>
        <Tab label="Item One" style={widthModifier} onActive={() => this.setState({ selectedIndex: 0 })}>
          <div>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>Tab One</h2>
            <p>
              You can put any sort of HTML or react component in here. It even keeps the component state!
            </p>
          </div>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label="Item Two" style={widthModifier} onActive={() => this.setState({ selectedIndex: 1 })}>
          <div>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>Tab Two</h2>
            <p>
              This is another example tab.
            </p>
          </div>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
      );
    }
}

export default TabWidth;
```

But, you really [should be using v1](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui#should-i-start-with-v1-beta) if possible. In material-ui v1, your desired tab behavior is the default [right out of the box](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tabs/#basic-tabs) and will scale based on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

I had this question. You need to just simply add `fullWidth` to `Tabs` component link:

```
<Tabs variant="fullWidth" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
  <Tab className={classes.root} label={t('login')} />
  <Tab className={classes.root} label={t('register')} />
</Tabs>
```

it worked for me.