# React Material UI tabs css

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Here I have attached my screen which is designed using react Material UI tabs.
[image: MaterialUI tabs]

It had two tab heading buttons as **Contribute component** and **Contribute idea**. I need to reduce the size of those two buttons but not the size of container which holds the input fields (ie: Select stack and Select Category). Also need to add a space between those headers and the input fields.I have tried with `style={{width:'50%'}}` property but it doesn't give me the required output. How can I achieve this

Comment: What version of material-ui are you using? v0 or v1?

Comment: Im using v0 @Jules Dupont

Comment: I have previously described how to change tab width in v0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499964/how-to-change-tabs-width-in-material-ui/48505058#48505058). Does that address your question? If not, how is your question different from changing the tab width?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a property called `tabItemContainerStyle` which is being used to modify the tab header. It is working fine for me